# C# LINQ find duplicates in List and remove one

Tags: c#, linq

How to find duplicate items from the list below and delete one?

```
var mylist = new List<string>(){
   "itemA.config",
   "itemA.en-us.config",
   "itemB.config",
   "itemC.config", 
   "itemC.en-us.config",
   "itemC.fa-ir.config"
};
```

If it has a value of "*.fa-ir.config", keep it. Otherwise, keep *.config

```
var mylist = new List<string>(){
   "itemA.config",
   "itemB.config",
   "itemC.fa-ir.config"
};
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've fully specified your problem.  I suggest you provide some sample inputs and outputs, enough to fully characterize your desired algorithm.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to be a little clearer, in case someone doesn't notice that your question is more complicated than "remove duplicates from a list of strings". You're not talking about true duplicates here, as it seems you would like to remove itemA.en-us.config, even though there is no other item that's identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GroupBy` (by `ItemA`, `ItemB` etc.) and then analyze each group:

```
var mylist = mylist
  .GroupBy(item => item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf('.')))
  .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault(item => item.EndsWith(".fa-ir.config")) 
                ?? group.FirstOrDefault(item => item.EndsWith(".config"))
                ?? group.First())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your logic: [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dk8D0T) Explanation below

```
mylist = mylist 
    .Select(s => (Name:s, Culture:GetConfigCulture(s, out string[] tokens), Tokens:tokens))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Tokens.First(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => GetOrder(x.Culture)).First().Name)
    .ToList();

string GetConfigCulture(string name, out string[] tokens)
{
    tokens = name.Split('.');
    if(tokens.Length < 3) return null;
    return tokens[1];
}

int GetOrder(string culture)
{
    if(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(culture, "fa-ir")) return 0;
    if(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(culture, null)) return 1;
    return 2;
}
```

So you want to remove duplicates according to the first token of the config name/path. If there a culture specific and one "global" you want to take that without culture. If it has the `"fa-ir"` culture, this has priority and should be taken.

So you need to group by the first and then order the items in each group by this logic, finally take the first to remove other duplicates.